# What is considered as data transfer in firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

What I considerd data transfare in firebase hosting according to docs

> Data transfer (GB/month) — The amount of data transferred to end users from our CDN. Every Hosting site is automatically backed by our global CDN at no charge

So is when a user go to my domain and firebase send the user my web site that lets say for the sake of argument has 100mb so each 10 requests will cost me 0.15 usd according the pricing on fire base ?

> Data transfer $0.15/GB

My current concern that my react build folder has the size of 3mb since it has too many pngs in it … so will I pay for the transfare of this build folder to end client each time a Client call this site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lets say for the sake of argument has 100 MB so each 10 requests will cost me 0.15 USD

Yes, you are charged on the data downloaded *from CDN/server*.

> My current concern that my react build folder has the size of 3mb since it has too many pngs in it

It'll be best to optimise and compress your images to reduce costs and also loading speed.

> so will I pay for the transfer of this build folder to end client each time a Client call this site

Some static assets should get cached locally so the next time user loads the site it might load them from cache instead of the server. So it won't be 3 MB always.

You can get rough estimate of the data being loaded in the network tab of browser console.

Comment: Does this mentioned cashing happens automatically ? Or should it logic it ?  , I want to optimize to PWA next month … but that’s a different topic , but about the local caching is it in this case done by the browser ?

Comment: @stop-error browser do cache static content but you can customise cache behaviour using cache `Cache-Control` headers. Checkout Firebase hosting's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache) _"By default, Cache-Control is set to private. This means that if you don't explicitly set Cache-Control to public, only the browser of the requesting user is allowed to cache the content."_

Comment: So if my data gets cached on CDN then I will save on data transfer ? , This what I understood from the docs you mentioned , in case if I flip the header to public ..?

Comment: You are charged for the data transfer between `CDN` and the user's browser. But if the asset is cached in that browser itself then a request to CDN/server is not sent and you won't be charged for that.

Comment: as you have said Some static assets should get cached locally , are you refereeing to caching using service worker or other type ? , I unregistered my service worker now each time i reload page I request images again and again.

Comment: I was referring to the browser cache.